# Create a script to disable Large Send Offload

Tags: powershell

I have to find a way to disable the LSO IPv4 thanks to a script.

How can I do it? Maybe with Powershell?

I'm not looking for a full solution even an idea can help me. Thanks.

edit: I need to diable LSO on a Windows 7 environment. So Disable-NetAdapterLso does not work and disabling Chimney does not disable either LSO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Disable-NetAdapterLso` cmdlet ([Documentation Link](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj130891(v=wps.630).aspx)) disables the state of the large send offload (LSO) settings, such as LSOv4 and LSOv6, on the network adapter.

Direct Registry change will do that also:

```
New-ItemProperty -Force -Path hklm:\\\\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\System\\CurrentControlSet\\Services\\TCPIP\\Parameters -Name LSOv2IPv4 -Value 0
```

Note: This should be the registry path

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class{4D36E972-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your help. What is the "name" in the Disable-NetAdapterLso cmdlet please?

Comment: @okok: Accepting the answer would be appreciable.

Comment: thanks! last question: is it possible to disable the state of the lso with Powershell 2.0?

Comment: You can use `netsh interface tcp set global chimney=disabled` or even `reg add HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters /v EnableTCPChimney
    /t REG_DWORD /d 0`

Comment: No but I used these commands and then checked if the LSO were disabled and it wasn't. Disable-NetAdapterLso works though.

Comment: If Disable-NetAdapterLso works then why you have removed the acceptance ?

Comment: bc i am supposed to disable the LSO with Powershell 2

Comment: That you haven''t mention that time. You should not undo like that. Thats what I meant. Its upto you buddy. I will look for version2 also.

Comment: Registry value tweaking will still support version 2